# Permission denied" while evaluating 'model.schedule_backup()'

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I already installed the module 'Database Auto-Backup Upload' in Odoo and in Schedule Actions, I run it manually but the error says:

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
ValueError: <class 'PermissionError'>: "13
Permission denied" while evaluating
'model.schedule_backup()'

I saw some comments that I need to give access right that folder to Odoo user but I don't know how can it be done on ssh in linux. I tried mkdir to create a folder but it always says permission denied.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the owner of your backup folder "/path/to/backup/folder" to the Odoo user (its name: `user=odoo` is set in your odoo configuration file: /etc/odoo/odoo.conf):

```bash
sudo chown -R odoo:odoo /path/to/backup/folder
```

Then, grant write permissions to this Odoo user:

```bash
sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/backup/folder
```

Find the name of the Odoo service

```bash
sudo systemctl list-units --type=service | grep odoo
```

...and restart it to apply the new permissions (its name is for example: odoo):

```bash
sudo systemctl restart odoo
```